# Neo4j : Introduction with basics?

Tags: neo4j

Hello everyone I am new to Neo4j, i am not able to get things like, How to query exactly and check its  result. Also does any other software necessary to make it work? if so then which.

Answer (score 1):

The manual should be able to answer all the questions you have: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/

Also, do check out http://www.neo4j.org/learn